# Script to copy from url and paste in file replacing certain content

Tags: replace, find, multiline

I'm trying to make a script which would automatically copy the entire content from WordPress's API service on [this address](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) and paste it in wp-config.php replacing the existing lines:

```
45: define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
46: define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
47: define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
48: define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
49: define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
50: define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
51: define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
52: define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');
```

What's the best way to go?

Comment: can you get the file from its URL using wget?

Comment: @arutaku I can, but I don't need the file, I need its content. I need somehow to copy the entire content of that file, paste it in another file and remove these other lines from the second file.

Comment: @arutaku actually, your hint helped me. I'll answer my own question in a second.

Comment: jajaja that sounds good. As advice, you can use wget -O - to get the web page as an input stream and avoid the temp file ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arutaku helped me with his hint about wget. I still don't think this solution is perfect (I'll explain why below), and would like to see if anyone has any other suggestion. But this one is still a valid option. So, my script:

```
    # Delete lines from 45 to 52 from wp-config.php 
    sed -i 45,52d wp-config.php
    # Get new lines and save them in a temporary file
    curl https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ > temp-salt
    # Insert temporary file content into wp-config.php after line 44
    sed -i '44r temp-salt' wp-config.php
    # Delete the temporary file
    rm temp-salt
```

The drawback is that this script manipulates with line numbers, rather than line content, and that's what makes it less than perfect. But `wp-content-sample.php` file is not likely to change very often, so I guess it's not all bad.